# Reading file from a local folder python after being imported from a parent folder

Tags: python-2.7

There is a file `main.py` in folder A.  Folder B is a subfolder of folder A.
There are files `subfolder.py` and  `data.txt` inside folder B. `subfolder.py` has a function which reads `data.txt` . Reading happens perfectly when I run the file `subfolder.py`

Now in `main.py` I import `subfolder.py` and call the function that reads `data.txt`
It says "no such file or directory `data.txt` "

Don't understand what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: try giving the exact path?

Answer (score 0):

could you please show your function in `subfolder.py`.

The program may be unsure of where the data.txt file is.
I would run this in your first file:

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Then add on to that string where it is needed

If python behaves in the way i expect it to behave, you may need to run something like

```
import os
filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\\"+"subfolder"+"\\"+"data.txt"
```

And then use filepath in the function in subfolder.py to open your data.txt.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
import os
previous_dir = os.getcwd() # Folder A
os.chdir('B') # Change to folder B

# Read data.txt

os.chdir(previous_dir)  # Change back to folder A
```